# Odds of being dealt 4 particular cards out of 106 in a 6 card hand

Tags: probability, card-games

I was playing a card game called [Mille Bornes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mille_Bornes) with my daughter.  She dealt a hand while I was getting a cup of coffee in the other room.  I came back and we started playing. She immediately played the four safety cards.  These cards not only prevent the other player/team from playing bad cards on you, you also get an extra turn after playing them.  I told her that it wasn't fun for me to play when the other person is cheating and that we could either play fair or not play at all.  My math's a bit rusty, so while I'm confident enough that the odds for her drawing that hand are slim-to-none, to put it mildly.  I was wondering what the exact odds were.

To sum up:

- 106 cards in the deck
- Each player is dealt 6 cards
- What are the odds of getting the 4 best cards in your initial hand?

Comment: In making a calculation, it is natural to assume that all choices of $6$ cards are equally likely. This assumption is false: shuffling is often an ineffective randomization device. When in tournaments players started to be dealt cards by a good pseudo-random number generator, they complained they were getting more "weird" hands than in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability is: $$\frac{\binom{102}{2}}{\binom{106}{6}}=\frac{6\cdot 5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{106\cdot 105\cdot 104\cdot 103}\approx \frac{3}{1,000,000}$$

So this happens about three times in a million hands.

That means every deal, with two players, the odds is about 6 in a million that *somebody* gets these four cards. But the odds that any specific player (say the dealer) gets a hand like this is still $3$ out of a million.

In the above expression, the numerator is the number of hands with these four cards - you can pick any other two cards from the remaining 102 cards. The denominator is the total number of possible hands - the number of ways of picking six cards out of $106$.